# Shoes installing error on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-14.04, shoes

Hello I have a problem with installing shoes on Ubuntu 14.04

I had install all things needed like make, gcc, cairo, pango and ruby.

this is the log from my terminal, it seems to have problem with some header, but I have no idea, google did not help me with this one.

```
$ make
cleaning
shoes build options:
CC       = cc
-e:1: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
RUBY     = /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547
OPTIONS  =
ruby 1.9.3p547 (2014-05-14 revision 45962) [x86_64-linux]
CC shoes/app.c
-e:1: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
In file included from shoes/app.c:5:0:
./shoes/app.h:14:18: fatal error: ruby.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ruby.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [shoes/app.o] Error 1
```

please keep in mind, I'm new to this so I can be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any real reason for building shoes from source? If not I would rather recommend to download the appropriate executable from http://shoesrb.com/downloads/, and run it into your machine. Works perfectly!